# The Sims 3-It Won't Update/Can't Use Expansion Packs

Tags: the-sims-3

Whenever I try launching The Sims 3, it asks me to update, and I press Yes. I just bought the Starter Edition, and I launch it, it doesn't register my new Expansion Packs, as Late Night comes with a map. It said I earned a map when I got Showtime Expansion Pack.[image]

[image]

The error:

[image]

Comment: ...There's no error in your second screenshot.  Just a list of games and DLC.

Comment: @Frank Oh sorry. Let me get the image up.

Comment: @Frank It should be fixed.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure this means that stop updating the game while trying to play the Showtime Expansion. :P